Estjs 6.2 Dynamic Tooltip with Hyperlink for Grid Cell
How can I create a dynamic tooltip with a hyperlink for the cells in a certain column? Can I do this in the renderer?

Do you use classic or modern toolkit?

We're using the classic toolkit.

In ExtJS classic toolkit you can use the grid column's renderer method to add tooltip and other customisation.
However, adding a hyperlink in the tooltip is problematic because the user can't click the tooltip in the grid: the tooltip is displayed somehow lower and to the right of the cell, and if you try to move the mouse over there, the tooltip disappears and the next row's tooltip is displayed.
My suggestion is to add the hyperlink to the cell itself, and optionally display a tooltip. Add this to the column of the grid where you need the tooltip:
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    metaData.tdAttr = Ext.String.format('data-qtip="{0}"', 'This is my custom tooltip.');
    return '<a href="https://www.sencha.com" target="_blank">' + value + '</a>';
}

You can use the record and other parameters of the renderer function to make it dynamic.

Thanks for your input. This is something we're already doing, but I wanted to see if we could actually put the link in a popup.
